# How to reconstruct the same directory and file structure and copypaste into other drive given the path to file urls in a notepad

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, file-transfer, file-management

I have around 2k png files located in different paths. I have all their path urls for example `T:\Pets\PNG1`, `T:\Pets\Dog\PNG2`, `T:\Birds\PNG3` in a notepad.

So how do I reconstruct the same directory and file structure and copypaste into other drive.

Like, i have those 3 above paths, then what is expected is  `D:\Pets\PNG1`, `D:\Pets\Dog\PNG2`, `D:\Birds\PNG3`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this !! So let me know if it doesn't work !!

---

> 1.txt

```
T:\Pets\PNG1
T:\Pets\Dog\PNG2
T:\Birds\PNG3
```

---

```
powershell -Command "(gc 1.txt) -replace 'T:', 'D:' | Out-File -encoding ASCII 2.txt"
```

> created `2.txt`

```
D:\Pets\PNG1
D:\Pets\Dog\PNG2
D:\Birds\PNG3
```

---

> copy.cmd

*{save this where the 1.txt and 2.txt are present and run}*

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file1=1.txt"
set "file2=2.txt"
set "out=out.txt"

set /a cnt=0
set "skip="

>"%out%" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%file1%") do (
    set "found="
    call :readFile2
    if not defined found (echo %%A - )
  )
)
type "%out%"
exit /b

:readFile2
for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%B in ("%file2%") do (
  set found=1
  move %%A %%B"
  goto :break
)
:break
set /a cnt+=1
set "skip=skip=%cnt%"
exit /b
```